# Create a variable list in LESS for colors variants based on a base color

Tags: css, less, less-mixins

In our project we use a LESS variables list. In this list we have multiple colors. For example this:

```
@color-gray: #B9B9BA;

@color-gray-light: lighten(@color-gray, 10%);
@color-gray-lighter: lighten(@color-gray, 20%);
@color-gray-lightest: lighten(@color-gray, 25%);
@color-gray-dark: darken(@color-gray, 10%);
@color-gray-darker: darken(@color-gray, 20%);
@color-gray-darkest: darken(@color-gray, 25%);
```

Besides this gray, we have other colors as well. So I would like to make a mixin that makes this list of variables for other colors.

The first color is defined. For example: @color-purple: #915E9F; and I want the mixing to create the remaining variables, solely based on this variable.

```
// Color - Purple    
@color-purple: #915E9F;

// Color variants generated by LESS for purple
@color-purple-light: lighten(@color-purple, 10%);
@color-purple-lighter: lighten(@color-purple, 20%);
@color-purple-lightest: lighten(@color-purple, 25%);
@color-purple-dark: darken(@color-purple, 10%);
@color-purple-darker: darken(@color-purple, 20%);
@color-purple-darkest: darken(@color-purple, 25%);
```

These variables will later be used all over the app to make up styling for buttons, headers, etc. I already have mixing that make these buttons, headers, variants.

Comment: Unfortunately dynamic variable names are not a part of LESS as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this you want to do?

```
@color-gray: #B9B9BA;


.colorset(@color) {
  @color-light: lighten(@color, 10%);
  @color-lighter: lighten(@color, 20%);
  @color-lightest: lighten(@color, 25%);
  @color-dark: darken(@color, 10%);
  @color-darker: darken(@color, 20%);
  @color-darkest: darken(@color, 25%);
}


.class{
  .colorset(@color-gray);
  color:@color-light;
}
```

**Demo:** http://codepen.io/blonfu/pen/ezBEje

Comment: This is slightly different than what I was thinking, but this would still work as I intended. Very awesome, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot create dynamic variables in mixin. But if you are willing to rethink your logic, you can do something like this:

```
.color-light (@colorItem) {
  @color-light: lighten(@colorItem, 10%);
}
.color-lighter (@colorItem) {
  @color-lighter: lighten(@colorItem, 20%);
}
.color-lightest (@colorItem) {
  @color-lightest: lighten(@colorItem, 25%);
}
.color-dark (@colorItem) {
  @color-dark: darken(@colorItem, 10%);
}
.color-darker (@colorItem) {
  @color-darker: darken(@colorItem, 20%);
}
.color-darkest (@colorItem) {
  @color-darkest: darken(@colorItem, 25%);
}

.class{
  .color-light(@color-gray);
  color:@color-light;
}
```

Comment: That is pretty unfortunate. We are building a React app, and I want to keep most of the styling classes outside of the templates. It just means I'll have to define the variables list manually, it's ok. :-)